# Is-Android-push-notification-using-GCM-free-of-cost

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are planning to develop the push notification service for a Android App. But I haven't got any information whether the GCMs push service is free of cost or should we make any payment?

My questions are,

Should I pay for using the GCMs push service?
If operator want to sent push notification to millions of subscribers, should we pay to Google or is it absolutely free? If not free, please share the URL where payment details are available.
Is there any limit for the number of notification sent or the number of subscribers?

Please help to get answer for these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read somewhere around few months ago, the limit is of 50,000 notifications per day. Sorry I don't have the link of it, maybe the limit might have changed. But I prefer to go with the Paid plan for notification.
Is this what you are looking for? or you can refer the following link [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: This is not true. There are no limits or paid plans.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is absolutely free of charge and there are no limits.